# MTKView texture correct color build-up

Tags: swift4, metal, render-to-texture, metalkit, mtlbuffer

I am working on a metal-backed drawing application where brushstrokes are drawn on an MTKView by stamping a textured square repeatedly along a path. I am having color-accumulation issues as illustrated with the picture below:

[image: snapshot of stamping implementation]

For alpha values [0.5 - 1.0] the results are more or less what I  expect.  However, for small alpha values, the result looks patchy and never achieves the uniform/correctly saturated value of the original **fully opaque** brush color (i.e. like the top brushstroke in above picture).

One key concept of my approach, is the following (perhaps flawed) implementation:  Say, the desired brushColor is blue, as above:

```
brushColor = (r: 0.0, g: 0.0, b:1.0, a: 1.0)
```

The way I set each stampColor is by dividing brushColor by the number of overlapping stamps:

```
overlapStampCount = n
stampColor = (r: 0.0/overlapStampCount, g: 0.0/overlapStampCount, b:1.0/overlapStampCount, a:1.0/overlapStampCount)
```

.

The idea being that n overlapping stamps will cumulatively add up to brushColor (blue).  Each stamp uses this stampColor at each vertex to multiply a white texture of a round blob with an alpha setting.  Below is my fragment shader:

```
fragment float4 basic_fragment(VertexOut interpolated [[stage_in]], texture2d<float>  tex2D     [[ texture(0) ]],
 sampler           sampler2D [[ sampler(0) ]]) {
   float4 color = interpolated.color * tex2D.sample(sampler2D, interpolated.texCoord); // texture multiplied by vertex color

   return color;
 }
```

.

Thus, based on this concept I set out to find a blending mode that would give me the desired result.  Through trial and error, I arrived at the following blending settings to achieve the result in the picture above:

```
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .one
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .one
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

.

On a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276449/transparency-issues-with-repeated-stamping-of-textures-on-an-mtkview?noredirect=1&lq=1), I had been advised to use "Source Over Compositing"

cdst′ = αsrc * csrc + (1 - αsrc) * cdst

...which translates to:

```
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

.

but the results are even farther from the desired outcome.

the texture I'm using is built from a png file (with transparency) as follows:

```
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)!.cgImage!
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    width = image.width
    height = image.height

let rowBytes = width * bytesPerPixel

let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: rowBytes, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!
let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int(width), height: Int(height))
context.clear(bounds)

if flip == false {
  context.translateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(self.height))
  context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
}

context.draw(image, in: bounds)

let texDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat.rgba8Unorm, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), mipmapped: isMipmaped)

texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: texDescriptor)
```

.

To sum up, my question is, how do I set up my textures/blending mode in a way that, for any stamp transparency value, the accumulated result of drawing in a region will eventually result in full color opacity?  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that your `stampColor` is computed incorrectly. I think you only want to divided the alpha component, not the blue component, by `overlapStampCount`. And then, yes, source-over compositing.

Comment: Thanks Ken.  I just tried both suggestions (fixing stampColor + "Source Over"), and the result is still not right.  Do you know if the "Source Over Compositing" settings I posted are correct?  I have no reference to know whether that is correct.

Comment: I think you want `sourceAlphaBlendFactor` to be `.one`.

Comment: Still nothing.  It occurs to me that, in addition to the stamp logic I've described, for performance issues, every N stamps, I create an uber stamp with the view's texture, and add this stamp to the MTLBuffer (so I don't have to draw an unlimited number of stamps).  I wonder if this stamp is the cause of my problems since I'm assuming that I'm obtaining proper rgba from it... Any ideas?  I really appreciate your time.

Comment: What is the value of `overlapStampCount`, roughly? Is it the number of stamps that will be on top of each other? Or through the whole shape, so that they are spread out? For any given pixel, how many stamps do you expect to actually hit that pixel?

Comment: Since stamps are spaced at a fixed distance, for small to large stamps overlapStapCount can vary between 2 - 50  (big stamps will span many more neighbors). At any given time, roughly 200 stamps are accumulated before they get captured into an uber stamp, at which point the next set of small stamps + the uber stamp get redrawn ... this gets repeated N times until user stops drawing

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem, and posted a more targeted question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272262/mtkview-blend-issues-when-re-using-currentdrawable-texture-in-draw-loop](here) . It seems the source-over-compositing works for the computed stamps, and not the Uber-stamp that uses the previous currentDrawable texture. Any thoughts would be most welcome.